# Mathjax latex validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, latex, mathjax

I am running into some trouble with my users not typing completely valid latex.

Consider the following (which is an excerpt from the end of a larger formula)

```
\left(x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1)
```

This is invalid as a \left tag should be accompanied by a \right tag.

Code-cogs equation editor will render this in its preview correctly, but once submitted and reloaded on my page with mathjax the formula is printed instead of rendered as it is incorrect (NoErrors plugin).

[image: NoError]

Does anyone know of a way to check if a mathjax formula is valid when submitting?  Allowing me to alert the user before saving the entry?

NB:  I could of-course manually render my own preview with mathjax but that would be a last resort solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say code-cogs renders it _correctly_ - it renders something, but the scaling of the right `)` is certainly not correct. More obvious if you add a fraction to the formula, e.g. `\left(x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1+\frac{1}{2})`.

Comment: My issue isn't in the formatting.  I want to inform the user before they post that the formula is invalid.

Comment: I understand that - my comment was more to the point of pointing out that code-cogs doesn't render stuff _correctly_ which would need some code fixing magic (which you might then have made use of to fix the formula before storing it).. and that obviously by having a close look at the code-cogs output the user will see there's some error in their code - which would of course be best combined with some programmatic check as you seek it.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a similar issue. If you have found any solutions, please post an answer to this!

Comment: Hey @FalconUA, I no longer have access to the code base where I solved this. Apologies for not posting my solution.  I do recall finding a solution after digging through the mathjax documentation intensively.  Good luck!